# Can a multiclassed Dreams druid/Storm Herald barbarian activate their Tundra Storm Aura while in Wild Shape?

Tags: dnd-5e, multi-classing, wild-shape, barbarian, rage

In my next campaign, I will be the solo healer, as a Circle of Dreams Druid.

I hope that will provide enough *Goodberry* and other healing skills to keep the party alive. But I really want to fight too. Because of that, I searched how can I be more supportive and be good in combat too. And I decided to multi-class with the Path of the Storm Herald barbarian. But now I am a little bit confused about whether I can always use Barbarian features as I thought.

I want to do some Tundra Storm Aura-raging while I am in my Wild Shape. Is that possible?

I need that feature to support my teammates with temp-HP while I am in the fight.

Comment: I've edited out your secondary question (and your broad "Is it possible to create some berryhealer-tanky character?" question at the end). I was almost sure there was already a generic Q&A about whether different AC calculations stack... But I'm having difficulty finding any exact duplicates, though there are questions about other combinations of AC calculations: [How do I calculate my AC for this character?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/161042/33569), [How does Mage Armor interact with Unarmored Defense?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/46569/33569)

Comment: Technically, this one seems like a duplicate of that secondary question about AC based solely on the title, though the calculation listed in the post is the monk's Unarmored Defense, not the barbarian's:  [Does natural armor stack with unarmored defense?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/53498/33569)

Comment: Thanks @V2Blast now I get my answer to my orignal question (Is all of the features work, not only the rage). I recognised the Lizardfolk AC calculation not as natural armor. But it is. Sorry for duplicated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## You can use Storm Aura while raging while Wild Shaping

While using Wild Shape you can't cast spells. Although Storm Aura is magical, it is not a spell, nor is it cast.

Wild Shape explicitly says "You retain the benefit of any features from your class, race, or other source and can use them if the new form is physically capable of doing so", so yes, it will work.